# Compare two dataframe columns in same dataframe and return text contained in first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data loaded into a dataframe but cannot figure out how to compare the parsed data against the other column and return only matches.

This seems like it should be easy but I just don't see it. I've tried splitting the values out to compare but here's where I get stuck.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': [';t9010;',';c1312;',';d1310;c1512;'],
                    'col2': [';t1010;d1010;c1012;',';t1210;d1210;c1312;',';t1310;d1310;c1412;']})

df['col1_split'] = df['col1'].str.split(';')
df['col2_split'] = df['col2'].str.split(';')


# output something like...
df['output'] = [null,';c1312;',';d1310;']
```

I'd expect to see something like -

1st row - return null, as `t9010` is not contained in `col2_split`

2nd row - return `c1312`, as it is in `col2_split`

3rd row - return `d1310` but not `c1512`, as only `d1310` is in `col2_split`

lastly, the final text should be returned semicolon delimited and with leading and trailing semicolons i.e. `;t9010;` or `;c1312;` or `;d1310;c1512;` if there is more than one.

Comment: Use backticks to add in-line code to a ``sentence``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part where you have tried to split using ";" is correct. After that, you need to compare each element in `col1_split` with each element in `col2_split`. You can write a simple function to avoid many loops and use `pandas` `apply` function to do the rest

Here is the sample code for the same

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': [';t9010;',';c1312;',';d1310;c1512;'],
                    'col2': [';t1010;d1010;c1012;',';t1210;d1210;c1312;',';t1310;d1310;c1412;']})

df['col1_split'] = df['col1'].str.split(';')
df['col2_split'] = df['col2'].str.split(';')

def value_check(list1, list2):
    string = ""
    for i in list1:
        if (i in list2) & (len(i)>0):
            string += ";"+i+';'
    return string

df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: value_check(x.col1_split, x.col2_split), axis=1)
df
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be can try this method to get all values in `col1` if its values are in `col2`. The method is by splitting string values in each row to a list and then omitting the empty values or length is less than 0 in the list values (`[]`) first. And then searching the values without empty values in `col1` that is matched to the `col2` and displaying the output to the `output` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': [';t9010;',';c1312;',';d1310;c1512;'],
                    'col2': [';t1010;d1010;c1012;',';t1210;d1210;c1312;',';t1310;d1310;c1412;']})

#splitting & omitting the empty values
df['col1_split']=df.col1.apply(lambda x: list((pd.Series(x.split(';')))[(pd.Series(x.split(';'))).apply(len)>0]))
df['col2_split']=df.col2.apply(lambda x: list((pd.Series(x.split(';')))[(pd.Series(x.split(';'))).apply(len)>0]))

def check(list1, list2):
    res=''
    for i in list1:
        if (i in list2): res += ';'+str(i)
    #semicolon cover at the end of string in each row
    if len(res)>0: res+=';'
    return res

df['output']=df.apply(lambda x: check(x.col1_split, x.col2_split), axis=1)
df
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

We can use a nested `list` comprehension for this:

```
df['common'] = pd.Series([[sub for sub in left if sub in right] for left, right in zip(df['col1_split'], df['col2_split'])]).str.join(';')

print(df['common'])
```

Output:

```
0          ;
1    ;c1312;
2    ;d1310;
Name: common, dtype: object
```